# How did Banner know Dr.Strange?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

*Hulk* gets transported via the *Bifrost* and ends up right next to *Dr.Strange*. But how did he know who Dr.Strange was to blurt out about *Thanos*? As far as I know these two haven't met anywhere before.

Of all the Marvel movies, *Dr.Strange* is the only one that I haven't seen, so I'm guessing Hulk had an appearance there, though it looks very unlikely?

If not, I wonder how Banner knew the persons standing right before him are special and not ordinary citizens.

Comment: Why does it matter who he said it too. You don't care who you're talking to to shout FIRE! It's the warning that counts...not who receives it.

Comment: As Paulie and Dave indicate, there's no reason to think this means that Banner "knows" Strange in any sense at all.  But if you want an unsupported conjecture reason...Banner is a top tier scientist, and Strange was a top tier neurosurgeon.   Though Banner works on entirely different matters, one may know the other through their scientific reputation and prominence alone.  Sort of like how you'd probably "know" Einstein, or Hawking, or DeGrasse Tyson.

Comment: Also, Thor made a cameo in the cutscene after credits of _Doctor Strange_, so it makes sense that Heimdall knew that Strange was an ally they could count in, since he probably send Thor there himself.

Comment: I think more of a question would be how _Heimdall_ knew Strange, and even if he knew, why would he send Banner to him instead of, say, Tony Stark ? Maybe he knew of the Time Stone being with Strange..?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Banner has not met Dr Strange, no.  At least, not in the MCU prior to Infinity War anyway.

However he just landed in a staircase, and was transforming back from the Hulk amidst the wreckage.  I'd say that he'd be likely to be babbling about Thanos to anyone who would listen at that point, regardless of whether or not they could do anything about it.

As it happens, they can, and Bruce would have recognised that they were not exactly "normal people" by way of the glowing sparking circles both had conjured around their hands as they stood over their "guest".  Bruce obviously calmed down enough to ask Dr Strange to find Tony Stark and things carried on from there.

Answer (score 2):

He spent his time with Thor who knows Dr Strange very well.
So it may possible that he came to know about him from thor initially.